# Google Analytics SiteSpeedSampleRate

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, appharbor

I want to track 100% of the timings for every page view since my site doesn't have too much traffic, ~1000 views per week. I read that the siteSpeedSampleRate defaults to 1%, that doesn't get me very many samples.

Most of the documentation that I found is for the old ga.js version, I'm using the analytics.js version (which I believe is still in beta). Anyway, what's wrong with my syntax here? I'm still not seeing any samples since I implemented this change this morning...Do I need to do something different since my site is hosted on Appharbor?

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x',
      {'cookieDomain': 'apphb.com',
       'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
```

[Here's a page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference) I've been using for my syntax, I found [another page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced) that shows how to setup multiple parameters here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way,

In your Tracking code **ga.js**

```
....
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 100]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
....
```

[More Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration)

---

**analytics.js**

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});  // Creates a tracker.
ga('send', 'pageview');    // Sends a pageview.
```

The first line calls the **create** command, and the second line calls the **send** command.

More [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#create) and [Advanced Configuration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced)

Comment: See comment above about analytics.js, NOT ga.js.

Comment: Are you check this link - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference

Comment: Since I'm using apphb.com to host my site, isn't that needed in the create line? The script that is auto-generated by Google Analytics has that so I figured the 'apphb.com' had to be there. If it doesn't, then it's an easy fix and I'll accept your answer.